# Insert a CSS file within a PHP class

Tags: php, html, css

I have a little problem, which I can't figure out by myself.
I created sort of a "webengine", which I build out of several classes.
The main-class, getting a "theme's" internals is called "Logic".

This logic-class includes all the files, needed for a website. I made it like that, so that every developer, creating such website could use function, that are given inside this class.

I now want to create a function, that allows these developers to include a CSS file. But this turns out to be quite difficult.

So far I tried this:

```
public function include_css($path_to_css) {
    $path_to_css = $this->project_name . THEMES . "/" . ACTIVE_THEME . "/" . $path_to_css;
    if(file_exists($path_to_css)) {         
        ?>
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" <?php echo $path_to_css; ?>" />
            </head>
        <?php 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
/* Idea number 2 */
public function include_css($path_to_css) {
    $path_to_css = $this->project_name . THEMES . "/" . ACTIVE_THEME . "/" . $path_to_css;
    if(file_exists($path_to_css)) {         
        echo "
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='".$path_to_css."' />
            </head>
        ";
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please note that unclarified attributes are declared in a complex matter, so it would be a very long post, if I would paste these here.

I am just getting this console error: http://127.0.0.1/vpm2/themes/numberOne/css/test.css 404 (Not Found), which means there is no such file. The interesting thing about that, is, that this is the exact path to the right file!

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Shouldn't the path be ` http://127.0.0.1/vpm2/themes/numberOne/css/test.css` ? You're getting the full root path, which is wrong.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. But it doesn't fix the issue. My test-div still ist affected by the css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently the CSS Path seems to be wrong. It needs to look like that:

```
$path_to_css = THEMES . "/" . ACTIVE_THEME . "/" . $path_to_css;
```

So the result looks like that:

```
themes/numberOne/test.css
```

Before it looked like that:

```
/vpm2/themes/numberOne/test.css
```